TS compiler confused about remapped paths in another workspace package
Context
Within a workspace (Bun/Yarn) I have a package server with this TS config:
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["*"]
    }
  },

From another package mobile I try to reference server via "@repo/server": "1.0.0" (Yarn) or "@repo/server": "workspace:*" (Bun) and then:
import { X } from "@repo/server";

but running tsc on mobile complains that:

../server/src/index.ts(1,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '~/api/something' or its corresponding type declarations.

(while running tsc on server yields a successful compilation).
Question
What am I doing wrong?
Additional resources
Repro repository (with Bun) here: https://github.com/shoooe/bun-module-resolution-with-workspaces-bug-repro
